# Can we pass form data to angular http request all at once

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I am wondering if it is possible to pass all the form data at once when performing an http request in Angular

My actuall angular http request;

```
$http({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'ajax-processor.php',
        data:  {'ajaxKey':'Mykey', 'angularQuery': 'login', 'username': $scope.username, 'password':$scope.password}
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
// dealing with response here
}
```

So Is there a way I can pass all the forms field to data. to avoid making all kind of diffrent request and have just one.

Comment: Highly suggest using the AngularJS directive `ng-model` so you don't have to use jQuery (which you really shouldn't mix into AngularJS if you can help it) -- docs here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel. Binding your form inputs to a scope variable with `ng-model` lets you handle form data as a serialized JSON object, which you can manipulate or pass around very easily to $http

Comment: Thats the first thing that came to my mind since im replacing jquery with angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure,

If you have jQuery available:

```
$('form').serialize();       // ---> "foo=1&bar=2"
$('form').serializeArray();  // ---> "[ { "foo": 1 }, { "bar": 2} ]"
```

The first gives you form data, the second gives you an array for use in JSON.

If jQuery isn't available and you're doing HTML5:

```
var data = new FormData(document.querySelector('form'));
```

And just pass that to your ajax method.

If you don't have HTML5 or jQuery, you can write the code yourself to serialize the form but it can be tricky, so I recommend some kind of library, such as `form-serialize`.

Comment: actually how would you hadle it on php side?
im using $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");